# Multiple domains/ranges for object property

Tags: java, netbeans, owl, ontology, owl-api

I am currently try to design an ontology but I am a new in this area. My ontology will have classes and object properties. No individual will be available.

I have an object property called `Has`. This property will have multiple domains and ranges. For example:

> Student (Class Domain) Has (Object Property) Department (Class Range)
>
> Mother (Class Domain) Has (Object Property) Child (Class Range)
>
> Organisation (Class Domain) Has (Object Property) Department (Class
>   Range)

I also expect more domains and ranges for the `Has` property to be added. I expect to have lot of object properties which will have multiple domains and ranges.

**How to write Java code to store such information in an OWL file?** Furthermore, I would like to know:

How to make a query to know how many domains and ranges a specific object property have and which domain matches which range?

How to write a code for finding does an object property has a specific triple? For example, `Has (School, Department)`. This triple means a School has a Department. If this triple is not available in the ontology, then I need to insert it into the ontology.

Comment: There is no specific query language for OWL but you could use SPARQL which in fact is the standard query language for RDF. On the other hand, if you're using the OWL API indeed you could simply write your "query" as Java method.

Answer (score 2):

Declaring domains and ranges with OWL API is done by creating OWLObjectPropertyDomainAxiom and OWLObjectPropertyRangeAxiom objects.

However, from your description of the problem I do not think that multiple domains and ranges for the same property are the best modelling solution. It's probably a better choice to have multiple object properties with their own domain and range, using multiple ones only when required.

For examples see https://github.com/owlcs/owlapi/wiki/Documentation